# Escrever um valor numa determinada posição do ecra, fora do form

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em Windows Forms, com o C#.
Por exemplo: Quero escrever um texto no campo de pesquisa do youtube, como pode ser visto através de:http://prntscr.com/ck0vo2

Alguém me consegue dizer como posso enviar uma string, frase, para uma determinada posição do ecra?

Eu neste momento já consigo posicionar o cursor e clicar no sitio em que é necessário escrever a string. Mas agora falta me a parte de efetivar a escrita da mesma.

Já consultei documentação sobre o SendKeys mas penso que não serve para mim...

Para mover o cursor para a posição que quero:

```
 //This is a replacement for Cursor.Position in WinForms
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
    SetCursorPos(10, 20);
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54244/discussion-on-question-by-leandro-rodrigues-escrever-um-valor-numa-determinada-p)

Answer (score 1):

Para quem necessitar encontrei um projecto, em c# que faz precisamente isto, basta estar com o cursor no sitio a escrever:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator/

Exemplo utilização:

```
InputSimulator i=new InputSimulator();
i.Keyboard.TextEntry("Ola mundo");
```